# Make borders same length in a border collapsed table

Tags: html, css, html-table

I have this code:

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>Test</th>
                <th>This</th>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>this</td>
                <td>out</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>test</td>
                <td>this</td>
            </tr>
       </table>
   </body>
</html>
```

With the CSS:

```
table {
    border-collapse: collapse;
}
tr{
    border-top: 1px solid black;
}
```

[fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/eg6gzz14/1/)

I am trying to get the borders to be the same length. So that the borders always use the full length of the `table`, instead of the `td`.

How would I do that?

My table is dynamic rendered with Vue so any fix that needs knowledge on how the table is visualized, I can't really use

Comment: In the code, you showed us, the table has no width? if it had, you could add in the css to the tr class the width property.

Comment: @newbie setting the width property on the table and make the tr `width: 100%` make no difference

Comment: I never mentioned the `width` prop to be 100% :)

Comment: @newbie then what do you suggest? I'm not sure I follow then.

Comment: First of all, in the fiddle you gave, the borders of the table are all identical, or is it just me? (please add a picture, of the table you see) And my suggestion is that you can edit thw width prop with the pixels, like 150px, or something :)

Comment: That way, if you fix the width of the table, you can exactly modify the length of the tr's as you wish.

Answer (score 0):

colspan attribute might help.

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Test</th>
    <th colspan="2">This</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>test</td>
    <td>this</td>
    <td>out</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
      <td>test</td>
    <td colspan="2">this</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

[JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/shuvo/uvchsxzw/)

Comment: anyway I can do it iva css? my table is dynamic rendered with Vue, so I can't know wich should be 2col